# Split XML data using multiple delimiters

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt, tokenize, delimiter

I have a tag in XML which contains a list of items, using multiple delimiters, such as:

`<List>1;Black;Colour;Smart,2;White;Colour;TV,3;Yellow;Pillow;Home</List>`

I need to split the values using XSLT (2.0 preferred) into this form:

```
<LIST>
 <LIST_ITEM id="1" value="Black" type="Colour" usedIn="Smart"/>
 <LIST_ITEM id="2" value="White" type="Colour" usedIn="TV"/>
 <LIST_ITEM id="3" value="Yellow" type="Pillow" usedIn="Home"/>
</LIST>
```

The delimiters are: `,` for separate list items and `;` for separate individual entries. There will only be 4 values in each List Item.

I'm guessing tokenize() is the most effective method to do this, but not sure how to. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="List">
  <LIST>
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ',')">
      <xsl:variable name="items" select="tokenize(., ';')"/>
      <LIST_ITEM id="{$items[1]}" value="{$items[2]}" type="{$items[3]}" usedIn="{$items[4]}"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </LIST>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it tokenizes first on a comma, the on a semicolon.

Comment: If I want to declare this template, and call it from within an Object, how can I do that?

Comment: Well you don't call such templates in XSLT, you push them to the XSLT processor using `xsl:apply-templates`. But the built-in templates do that for you so the above code is complete. And I don't know what "call it from within an Object" is supposed to mean in the context of XSLT. You need to explain that.

Comment: Okay, I removed the template thing and it worked. I was using other attributes as well. Thanks a lot!